# Issue with dynamic fields in MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am using mongodb in my rails application.

Suppose I have a mongo model as below

```
class Product
 include Mongoid::Document
   field :test, type: String
   field :link, type: String
end
```

Then it works fine

But when I add these fields dynamically by generating them in a lib or for example as below in my controller

```
params[:product][:test]="Test Value"
params[:product][:link]="Test Link"
```

Then I get the error as below Mongoid Error(Screenshot attached)
[Error ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEisx.png)

Please Help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is some private method `test`. In my project:

```
> Account.new.test
NoMethodError: private method `test' called for #<Account:0x007f89e60afd30>

> Account.new.send :test
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)
```

Comment: even I get the same error, but it works when we have a field initialized explicitly... as `field :test` and `field :link` why?
there is one more such keyword that I have came across `desc`. can anybody explain the difference, why it works on explicit declaration and not while dynamic field generation?

Comment: Because if you declare them as fields, Mongoid creates public accessors for you

Comment: so, is there any workaround for this, as I have dynamic field navigation, where user decides the field name, and I cannot stop the user from creating random field names, so what can be a better solution??

Comment: Anyway you need to check field names, because he can add field with reserved name, which can be destructive. I see two ways:

Comment: 1. You check, that this is not method name via `respond_to?` method.

Comment: 2. You add prefix to user's field, so `test` becomes `user_test`

Comment: I do not want to restrict the user with specific field names, anyways, test and link are the most common names that a user tries when using any product

Comment: Looks like you don't need any more advices :) Good luck!